# calculate the days between two dates

Tags: c

I did a program that calculates the days different, between two dates, but I am not sure how can I add a statement that makes sure the program wont include the end date.

then will only include the end date, if I write the word include after writing the two dates! for instance the program will say the following ./daysCalulcatorA dd1 mm2 yyyy1 dd2 mm2 yyyy2, and the end date ( dd2 mm2 yyyy2 will not be included, until i write the word "incude" like this: 
./daysCalulcatorA dd1 mm2 yyyy1 dd2 mm2 yyyy2 incude

for example:

```
/daysCalulcatorA 19 2 2019 22 4 2019 include
```

How do i do that?

Comment: `if (argc >= 8 /* && argv[7][0] == 'i' */) includelast = 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if argv[7] is "include" using strcmp from `<string.h>`, and set a variable to ignore the end date if it's not

```c
    /* Rest of the code above */

    if (mm2<mm1) {
        mm2 += 12;
        yyyy2 -= 1;
    }

    int include = 0;
    if (argc >= 8)
    {
        if (strcmp("include", argv[7]) == 0)
        {   
            include = 1;
        }
    }

    day_diff = dd2 - dd1;
    if (include == 0)
    {
        day_diff--;
    }
    printf("%d", day_diff);

    return 0;
```

But i recommend you search about `getopts`, a flag seems more user friendly
`./daysCalculatorA -i 19 2 2019 22 4 2019`

Comment: i am getting 32755 when i write include this time and 25 without it

Comment: That looks like an uninitialized variable or a signed integer overflow, are you putting the rest of the code, like `day_diff = dd2 - dd1` where is the `Other parts of the code` comment? I couldn't reproduce the same issue here

Comment: int dd1 = 0;
  int mm1 = 0; 
  int yyyy1 = 0; 
  int dd2 = 0; 
  int mm2 = 0; 
  int yyyy2 = 0; 
  int day_diff;
  int include = 0;
    if (argc >= 8)
    {
        if (strcmp("include", argv[7]) == 0)
        {   
            include = 1;
        } 
    then the rest of the code and after that:
  if (include == 0)
  {
  day_diff = dd2 - dd1;
  }
  printf(" %d ", day_diff);
 
  return (0);
}

Comment: Don't put the `day_diff = dd2 - dd1;` inside of the `if (include == 0)`, put it above instead, and `day_diff--;` (for subtracting a day) inside it, like on the answer

Comment: one last question please! what if i didnt want end date included in all cases?

Comment: Then you could subtract 1 from `day_diff` directly, without the if statement, like
`day_diff = dd2 - dd1 - 1;`

Comment: I am sorry for the asking so many questions! but my teacher has the answer for ./daysCalculatorA 14 9 2019 9 12 2019 to be 86 days, so why is it 24 with me?

Comment: Probably that's related to other part of the code, some calculation that you did wrong

Comment: yeah, my code is calculating month and days but only printing days, its 86 days or 2 months and 25 days! how do i edit that so it shows 86?  if i am not asking too much

Answer (score 0):

> my code is calculating month and days but only printing days, its 86 days or 2 months and 25 days! how do i edit that so it shows 86?

This is a typical case of "Don't (try to) reinvent the wheel." Use the Standard C [`mktime`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_mktime.htm) function to convert broken-down times into time values which can be subtracted from each other.

```
#include <time.h>
…
  time_t t1, t2;
  t1 = mktime(&(struct tm){ .tm_mday=dd1, .tm_mon=mm1-1, .tm_year=yyyy1-1900 });
  t2 = mktime(&(struct tm){ .tm_mday=dd2, .tm_mon=mm2-1, .tm_year=yyyy2-1900 });
  day_diff = (t2 - t1) / 24 / 60 / 60 + include;    // make days from seconds
```