# Calculate the days between two dates, but the results are wrong

Tags: c

I did a program that calculates the days different, between two dates, but it is calculating months and days, yet only printing days, like, for example, if its  2 months and 25 days, its only printing 25 days, I want it to calculate in days only so the answer wont be 2 months and 25 days, but 68 days alone.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
  /* Names of the months */
  char *monthName [12] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", 
"September", "October", "November", "December" };
  /* The number of days in each month */
  int monthLength[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
  int dd1 = 0;
  int mm1 = 0; 
  int yyyy1 = 0; 
  int dd2 = 0; 
  int mm2 = 0; 
  int yyyy2 = 0; 
  int day_diff;
  if ( argc < 4 ) { 
    printf ( "usage: ./daysCalculcatorA dd1 mm2 yyyy1 dd2 mm2 yyyy2 \n" );
    exit ( 1 );
  } else { 
    dd1 = atoi ( argv[1] );
    mm1 = atoi ( argv[2] );
    yyyy1 = atoi ( argv[3] );
    dd2 = atoi ( argv[4] );
    mm2 = atoi ( argv[5] );
    yyyy2 = atoi ( argv[6] );
  }
  if ( dd2 < dd1)  { 
    if(mm2 ==3) 
    {
      if ((yyyy2 % 4 == 0 && yyyy2 % 100 != 0) || (yyyy2 % 400 == 0))  {
        dd2+=29;
    }
      else 
      { 
        dd2+=28;
      }
    }
    else if (mm2 ==5 || mm2 ==7 || mm2 ==10 || mm2 ==12)
    { 
      dd2+=30;
    }
    else
    {
      dd2 +=31;
    }
    mm2 = mm2 -1;
  }
  if (mm2<mm1)
  {
    mm2 += 12;
    yyyy2 -= 1;
  }
  day_diff = dd2 - dd1-1;
  printf(" %d ", day_diff); 
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Please fix the code

Comment: Tips: Try to use meaningful variable names. Format+indent your code properly (and when posting here, put a line with `~~~` above and below the code). Test your code with small test cases ... exploring where your logic is not yet correct.

Comment: Following OP's recent [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57964129/calculate-the-days-between-two-dates).

Answer (score 0):

See [mktime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/) example how to create 2 **struct tm** objects, and then you could easily compare them.